# Displaying maps in Processing

Tags: android, google-maps, processing

I want to create a [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) application in Android mode, which

1. displays a map of a city (from Google, Yander or Open Street Maps),
2. allows the user to move the map (like in the Google Maps app on mobile devices),
3. zoom in and out and
4. displays coordinates of a place, when the user taps there.

Are there any examples of similar applications or tutorials how to make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial using TileMill to render maps:

http://tillnagel.com/2011/06/tilemill-for-processing/

In addition, here is a great Processing forum thread on the topic:

http://forum.processing.org/topic/processing-and-maps

You could use OpenStreetMap to render the maps, but their XML format takes a long time to parse.  I would recommend using the tool [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) to convert the OSM file into a database.  You can then feed your Processing maps system the maps through the database.

If you could somehow use the traditional Java way of creating an Android app, I would do that because Google's new vector maps are very fast, and from what I've experienced Processing's Android App Generator can be a little sketchy sometimes.

EDIT:  Here is how to write Processing in Java.  It was a bit too detailed to put in the comments.

In the Processing [FAQ](http://wiki.processing.org/w/FAQ#I_know_Java.2C_is_this_Java.3F_How_do_I_use_it_that_way.3F), there is a question entitled "I know Java, is this Java? How do I use it that way?".  In the answer, the author states that "Processing is converted to straight java when you hit the run button."

To elaborate on that, the author also made a [tutorial about using Processing within Eclipse](http://processing.org/learning/eclipse/).  Essentially, you use Processing's `core.jar` file to write your Java Applets.  I'm not sure if this would play well with Google Maps, but it's a worth a shot.

Comment: Is it possible to mix Processing and Java (use traditional Java where performance is needed) ? Like inline Assembler in the old days of C.